# Equivalent of typeof(class) for custom attribute

Tags: c#, attributes, custom-attributes

Is there an equivalent of `typeof( )`  for a custom attribute?

Specifically I would like to rewrite this code in such a way where I wouldn't rely on string comparison

```
if (prop.GetCustomAttributes(true).Any(c => c.GetType().Name == "JsonIgnoreAttribute")) { ... }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an [overload of `GetCustomAttributes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwc6ew1d.aspx) which takes the type you want as a parameter:

```
prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(JsonIgnoreAttribute), true)
```

**But** as you're actually checking for the presence of the attribute, you should rather use [the `IsDefined` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130876.aspx):

```
if (Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(JsonIgnoreAttribute), true))
```

This does not instantiate the attributes, and is therefore more performant.

If you didn't need the *inherit* parameter, you could have written:

```
if (prop.IsDefined(typeof(JsonIgnoreAttribute)))
```

For some reason, this parameter is *ignored* in the `MemberInfo.IsDefined` function of properties and events, but taken into account in `Attribute.IsDefined`. Go figure.

Note that any type *assignable* to `JsonIgnoreAttribute` will be matched by these functions, so derived types will also be returned.

---

As a side note, you could have directly compared the `Type` objects like this:
`c.GetType() == typeof(JsonIgnoreAttribute)` (is it the *exact* same type?),
or `c is JsonIgnoreAttribute` (is the type *assignable*?).

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with using `typeof()`? or better yet, `is`?

```
if (prop.GetCustomAttributes(true).Any(c => c is JsonIgnoreAttribute))
```

You could also do:

```
if (prop.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<JsonIgnoreAttribute>().Any())
```

or

```
if (prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(JsonIgnoreAttribute), true).Any())
```